# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running libgdx app on Android

Tags: java, android, libgdx, noclassdeffounderror

I got this error when running my libgdx project on Android, the Desktop project works fine.

FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.alexdev.oldcrt.PostProcessing

PostProcessing is a new class that I've created, here I add pictures of Java Build Path. Thanks in advance.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvSWg.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4mw3.png

Comment: Here I add two others messages on log:
Info: I/dalvikvm(7489): Failed resolving Lcom/alexdev/oldcrt/PostProcessing; interface 1038 'Lcom/bitfire/postprocessing/PostProcessorListener;'
Warning: Link of class 'Lcom/alexdev/oldcrt/PostProcessing;' failed

Comment: I think you also have to mark the contribs to export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it adding in the android-project's build path all the projects that were in the main-project, and mark to exporting them. The reason for this is that an Android Eclipse project no longer adds the sources of referenced Java projects to the APK it compiles.